# Cloning existing project of Angular2

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

[enter image description here][1]I cloned my existing project from git hub, now trying to install angular-cli facing errors.

```
    Vipins-Air:angular2 vipingupta$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm ERR! path /Users/vipingupta/.npm-global/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/vipingupta/.npm-global/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /Users/vipingupta/.npm-global/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/vipingupta/.npm-global/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vipingupta/.npm/_logs/2017-06-06T05_22_33_327Z-debug.log
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVBsz.png my log file link attached

Comment: Can you show us your log which is stated in your error? It appears that you have already installed angular-cli on your computer.

Comment: okay Thanks! let me pull it up

Comment: I am running same command but it freeze my terminal:- normalizeTree: sill install loadCurrentTree

Comment: @Edric please check image attached

Comment: Can you try just typing in `ng` in your console?

Comment: Trying to fix it and got this now            Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
  /Users/vipingupta/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@3.10.10 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm